# What is difference between these two Probabilities?

Tags: probability, random-variables

What is difference between these two Probabilities:
1) Getting six on rolling a dice 6 times.
2) Getting six on rolling 6 dices.
I am confused between these two.

Comment: Is there a difference from a probabilistic point of view? Assuming that all dice are fair...

Comment: Can you please tighten up your question? Do you mean "exactly one 6, not multiple 6s"? And if so, in case (1), do you stop as soon as you get a 6? And can we assume "fair dice"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between rolling the same die six times, and rolling six different dices, assuming all the dice are of the same make and are fair. This is simply because all dice rolls are independent of each other, and there are precisely six dice rolls in both.

You should elaborate your point of confusion further if you want to get rid of it. Keep track of which events are independent and which are not. This will help you tackle these kind of problems.